# Is Amazon AWS IoT recognised as being compliant with oneM2M standards?

Tags: networking, standards

I would like to know if [Amazon AWS IoT](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-platform/) are acknowledged as being compliant with the standards published by [oneM2M](http://www.onem2m.org/). Specifically, the [Functional Architecture](http://www.onem2m.org/images/files/deliverables/Release2/TS-0001-%20Functional_Architecture-V2_10_0.pdf) standard seems relevant to the layer that AWS IoT provides.

**Is this something which Amazon specifically support, or is there any evidence that these standards are complied with by AWS IoT?**

Comment: Can you add a reference to this oneM2M standard?

Comment: Lists don't suit this fomat well, it is hard to maitain them and keep them up to date.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I assume it's [this](http://onem2m.org/) standard. OP, is this correct?

Comment: Amazon certainly don't appear on their [partner list](http://www.onem2m.org/membership/current-members). I'd have thought such a high profile candidate would have been included if they'd opted for the scheme.